# Data extract from and object issue javascript

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I have json data like

```
    [ [ RowDataPacket { content_id: 52 } ],
  OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 } ]
```

How I get content_id part from this data set?

I got this data while calling a Stored Procedure using TypeORM.
here is the code I tried

```
const contentData = await connection.getRepository(Content).query('CALL getInitialContent()');
```

Comment: It is not a valid json, indeed. Anyways, you might share what you have tried so far, or at least, which language you use.

Comment: 1) this is not actually valid JSON. Where are you seeing this format of the data? It's a bit closer to being valid as a JavaScript object literal (although still not correct) - maybe you are getting confused between that and JSON (which is a serialised text format, not a programming object)? 2) You want to get a value from it...but using which programming language? The approach might differ considerably from language to language, even once you've accounted for the fact that it's not parseable as JSON as shown.

Comment: It's not a json

Comment: `[0][0].content_id`

Comment: Your data should be something like this to be valid,



`[ 
    [ {RowDataPacket: { content_id: 52 }} ],
    {OkPacket: { fieldCount: 0, affectedRows: 0, insertId: 0, serverStatus: 2, warningCount: 0, message: '', protocol41: true, changedRows: 0}} 
];`

Comment: I updated my question.Please tell me how to get content_id

Comment: @SupunAravinda based on the data you've shown, Nick McCurdy's code should _not_ work. I have answered below showing what would work based on the info given. However as I mentioned earlier, than info is potentially ambiguous. So if the situation is different for you, you need to show us a clearer, valid example of the data.

Answer (score 0):

To be a valid JS object literal, your data would have to look like this:

```
[
  [ { RowDataPacket: { content_id: 52 } } ],     
  { OkPacket: { fieldCount: 0, affectedRows: 0, insertId: 0, serverStatus: 2, warningCount: 0, message: '', protocol41: true, changedRows: 0}
   }  
];
```

Once you have that, then getting the content_id field is reasonably trivial as long as you can comprehend the data structure - it's inside the first element of an array, which itself is an array. The first element of that inner array is an object. That then contains another object inside the "RowDataPacket" object, and and the content_id data you want is a property of that second object.

Shorthand version:

```js
let data = [
  [{
    RowDataPacket: {
      content_id: 52
    }
  }],
  {
    OkPacket: {
      fieldCount: 0,
      affectedRows: 0,
      insertId: 0,
      serverStatus: 2,
      warningCount: 0,
      message: '',
      protocol41: true,
      changedRows: 0
    }
  }
];

let id = data[0][0].RowDataPacket.content_id;
console.log(id);
```

Longhand (so you can see the traversal of the data hierarchy step by step):

```js
let data = [
  [{
    RowDataPacket: {
      content_id: 52
    }
  }],
  {
    OkPacket: {
      fieldCount: 0,
      affectedRows: 0,
      insertId: 0,
      serverStatus: 2,
      warningCount: 0,
      message: '',
      protocol41: true,
      changedRows: 0
    }
  }
];

let arr = data[0]; //get inner array
let obj = arr[0]; //get object inside the array
let packetObj = obj.RowDataPacket; //get object in the RowDataPacket property
let id = packetObj.content_id; //get the target data
console.log(id);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.yes of course if I get this data like { RowDataPacket: { content_id: 52 } } then I can access what you are saying.But the case is this data set format is not created by myself.It's return from typeorm.How ever I resolved this issue according to the user  @ Nick McCurdy .Thanks again for your explanation

Comment: " this data set format is not created by myself"..that isn't my point. The point is that the data format you showed in the question includes RowDataPacket. If that isn't the real data structure, then why did you show it? You should show the real structure. Because Nick's solution will not work with the data you showed.

Comment: your data structure contain : (colon) between RowDataPacket and { content_id: 52 }.But my one does not contain it

Comment: Ok. But simply removing the colon would make the code invalid. It cannot be interpreted as a Javascript object if you do that. Here is the proof: https://jsfiddle.net/0q2m53tg/ . Same with the Okpacket. That's why I'm saying you need to show some valid data. I don't know where you got this data from, that you showed in the question? Is it the output from some console or debugging tool? They do not always show parseable code. Better to find the real code or data, or serialise it to JSON to get valid, usable output that everyone can understand fully.

Comment: yes.I'm agree with you.I got this data when calling stored procedure using TypeORM library.I can't change their data set.That's why I was searching a way to extract them properly

Comment: "I can't change their data set."...no that's not what I'm asking you to do. You're misunderstanding my point. I'm asking you to provide a valid sample of the data, instead of one which doesn't compile, and is therefore ambiguous about its real structure.

Comment: valid structure to I can extract,I posted this question to get an answer for this kind of data set

Comment: If you can extract a valid structure then please do so, so we can see it. What you have shown in your question is **not** valid. I proved it with my jsFiddle link. Therefore it's not usable in an answer. I suggest maybe serialising your data to JSON and showing us that output instead. It's not clear where you are getting the output in your question from in the first place.